# autofill with a formula that contains " " in it

Tags: microsoft-excel, macbook, auto-form-fill

I am using a mac product to complete this task!

I have a spreadsheet with names of storms and their wind speeds at different times. I am required to find their maximum wind speed. I used the `MAXIFS` function:

```
=maxifs(windspeed column, name of storm column, "name of storm")
```

Now I am trying to autofill the remaining storm names (there are 180 in total) but of course when I drag down, I am getting the same value because the "name of storm" isn't changing. What do I need to click/do so that when I autofill the formula excel will automatically pull the name from each storm to give me the value I need?

[image: Example data]

Comment: do you have the a unique list of the storms?  If so just change `"name of storm"` to the first cell reference then drag it down and it refer to the next in the list.  If you do not have that list then you will need to get it.  If you have office 365: `=Unique(name of storm column)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example you provided, it appears that in column A you have the unique list of storms for which you want to find the maximum wind speed value in column Q based on the corresponding name in column L.

Thus, simply but in cell B18 the updated formula:

```
=MAXIFS(Q:Q,L:L,A18)
```

The formula now takes the name listed in column A as input, and when you drag the formula down, the "name of storm" is automatically adjusted.